Probability of at least two people having the same birthday
I know that this is a very common problem but I have a specific question regarding why my method was wrong.
Problem: Find the smallest number of people $n$ such that the probability of two people having the same birthday is > 1/2. Assume that there 365 days in the year.
We do the following calculations assuming there is $n$ people in total. Then $P(\text{at least 2 people have same birthday}) = 1 - P(\text{no 2 people have the same birthday}).$ We can calculate \begin{align*}
P(\text{no 2 people have the same birthday}) &= \#(\text{ways to have no people have same birthday})/\#(\text{ways to assign birthdays without restrictions}) \\
&= \frac{{365 \choose n}}{\#(\text{weak compositions of } n \text{ into 365 parts})},
\end{align*} where $\#(\text{weak compositions of } n \text{ into 365 parts}) = {365 + n - 1 \choose n} = {364 + n \choose n}$.
However, the solution is that the denominator is $365^n$, which also makes sense. So where did I go wrong?
I believe that the numerator treats days as distinguishable, and people as indistinguishable (since ${365 \choose n}$ only selects the days that people have birthdays, not which person has which distinct birthday). However, my denominator should do the same, as in stars and bars, the stars are indistinguishable whereas the bars are distinguishable (ordered). In the case of using $365^n$ as the denominator, we would require an implicit ordering of the people (treated as distinguishable).

The problem with your approach is that weak compositions of $365$ into $n$ parts (or stars and bars over non-negative integers as it is more commonly known as) aren't equi-probable You can understand, e.g. that all having the same birthday would be much much more improbable than a more even distribution of birthdays. That is why  we imagine that the people are arranged in a line, and for all birthdays to be different. the first person has $365$ choices, the second person $364$ choices and so on for $n$ terms, thus
$365⋅364⋅363\cdots(365-n+1)$
which can be more conveniently written as a permutation $^{365}P_n$ or a falling factorial $365^\frac{n}{~}$ in the numerator and $365^n$ equi-probable possibilities in the denominator.
The ratio of the two, of course would give the probability  that none of the $n$ people have common birthdays, and the probability that at least  two people have a common birthday would be its complement,
$$Pr = 1- \frac{365^\frac{n}{~}}{365^n}$$
The key point you need to remember is that stars and bars does not give equi-probable outcomes.
And, of course, people are distinct !

I think $365^{\underline n}$ is a bit clearer than $365^{\frac n~}$, but I suppose it is a matter of taste.

@MishaLavrov: What you suggest is actually simpler to type in, I prefer the latter only because the underline comes out clearer.

Thank you for your answer! However, I don't understand why equi-probability matters. I am calculating the probability by counting the total number of possible outcomes, and I don't believe that the probability of each outcome matters.

Oh I see why that matters: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084789/birthday-problem-want-about-using-unordered-counting.
